# osm2pgsql and postgresql 9.1 from homebrew failing to connect on Mac

Tags: postgresql, homebrew, openstreetmap

I have installed osm2pgsql and postgresql (9.1) with homebrew, and I have confirmed that /usr/local/bin/osm2pgsql and /usr/local/bin/psql are the versions being used by my system (with which psql, which osm2pgsql).

When I try to run osm2pgsql I get a strange connection error:

```
osm2pgsql us-south.osm.pbf -r pbf
osm2pgsql SVN version 0.80.0 (32bit id space)

Error: Connection to database failed: could not connect to server: Permission denied
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/pgsql_socket/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Any suggestions? I can connect locally to my databases fine with Navicat and via psql.

Answer (score 4):

adding  "`-H localhost`" solved the issue for me.

e.g.:

```
osm2pgsql us-south.osm.pbf -H localhost -r pbf
```

see [here](http://cartometric.com/blog/2012/12/18/osm2pgsql-and-windows-errors-failed-to-start-msvcr90-dll-connection-to-database-failed-etc/).